# Injecting a click listener on an image overlay service

Tags: android, service, overlay, inject

I've managed to implement a overlay service which has an image, it can be moved in the application. But I m trying to inject a click listener on the overlay-service so that when I press on it, for instance a button which is under the overlay-service then it should pass the click to the underlying button and gets pressed on. I've tried to look around but with no luck.
Any tips of how to do this in a smart way?

This is the code for moving the overlay

```
overlayView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsF = params;
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;

            @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    // Get current time in nano seconds.

                    initialX = paramsF.x;
                    initialY = paramsF.y;
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    paramsF.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                    paramsF.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(overlayView, paramsF);
                    break;
                }
                return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to override the ontouchlistener so it does not consume the event but instead passes that on to the next layer? Im not super clear about what you are trying to do but if we are on the same page that is what u want.

Comment: Yes exactly!  how can I override it so that it passes the click onto the next layer?

Comment: if the click is consumed the method returns true if it wasnt it returns false. so if u want to make the event that took place something that the overlay consumes return true else return false and the android system should propagate that through on its own.

Comment: not sure what you mean, but isn't it possible to do it somehow with the ontouchlistener?? 
- I provided the code in the post

Comment: that should theoretically pass the click through to the next layer.

Comment: But it dosen't seems to work when I click, it dosen't pass the click to the button which is behind the overlay